# Confirm user's selection of "Don't Allow" location services

Tags: cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I am using location services in my app. Initially the app asks the user to allow finding the current location. If the user says "Don't Allow", can I show one more alert to confirm that choice? Then, if the user says "Allow" in that second dialogue, can the app get the current location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, it is managed by the the system.

You can/should check if the user allowing you app to get the current location.
Because you can change this in the settings app

Check can be done like this:

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
   // location can not be retrieved.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think..................
its a not possible beacuse its a default setting of iPhone ....

if u get answer please reply ....in this page......
 but u change the setting of iphone, go to setting icon , go to general icon , go to current location and on this button...

sry for poor english

Answer (score 0):

The question is who is showing the second message.
If it's CoreLocation that is showing the message than the last answer is the one that counts - so if it was "allow" then you can.

However - if after the "Disallow" you show your own custom message - the answer there has no affect.
It must come from CoreLocation

Comment: CoreLocation will show the message second time if you disallowed it the first time. After the second time the message will not appear again. (only if you remove the app and reinstalled it will the message apear again)